# Glassfish 4 netbeans 7.4

Tags: jpa, netbeans, glassfish-4

I am having an issue with Glassfish 4.0 using netbeans 7.4.
The 'Enable JDBC Driver Deployment' in netbeans is grayed out.
I am unable to deploy the data resources from netbeans to Glassfish .
What am i doing wrong ?
The glassfish server is on a different machine.
I have the values in the glassfish_resources.xml ,they however dont get deployed to the server

Comment: what error show on output??

Answer (score 0):

Does a entity manager need some entities in order to be deployed ?